# Get info from a private Vimeo video using Advanced API and PHP

Tags: php, api, video, vimeo

I have a php app and i'm trying to get the video info from a private Vimeo video (my video).
I'v read through the [Advanced API documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced) and i have successfully authenticated my app. I use the official php library.

I have been able to get a video list with the [getAll](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.videos.getAll) method:

```
require_once('./vimeo/vimeo.php');
$vimeo = new phpVimeo('xxxx', 'xxxx');
$vimeo->setToken('xxxx','xxxx');

$videos = $vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.getAll', 4272839);
```

What i need is to **get the video by the video id** so i have to use the **getInfo** method. I can successfully fetch the video info using the Playground but in my app i get this error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'VimeoAPIException' with message 'Video not found' in app_root/vimeo/vimeo.php:239
```

'Video not found' according to the getInfo documentation says, either invalid id or "**video not viewable by the calling user**".

I don't know how to continue form here so if anyone have a suggestion i would be thankful!

Answer (score 0):

Your video seems to work with video.getInfo even when unauthenticated. Try making the request without the line `$vimeo->setToken('xxx','xxx');`.

If an unauthenticated request works, but authenticated does not I assume that something is strange with your authentication tokens. Make an authenticated request to people.getInfo (without the user_id) parameter to identify who the authentication token belongs to. If the token is authenticated to a user different than the video owner there is a problem.

If this doesn't help, Vimeo can provide more direct assistance if you send your access token and client id (do not send the secrets!) to vimeo.com/help/contact.